# How to refresh a table after a successfull Post using $evalAsync

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I need to update my table after a successful Post without reloading the page. I have it working for a successful Put but I cannot get it to work with the Post.
Works

```
 //Update Job 
$scope.updateJob = function (job) {
    jobFactory.updateJob(job)
        .success(successCallback)
        .error(errorCallback);
    console.log(job);
    $scope.cancelEditJobModal();
    $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
        $scope.job;
    });
};
```

Doesnt't Work

```
//Post New Job
$scope.submitJob = function () {
    var data = {
        JobId: $scope.newItems.JobId,
        JobNumber: $scope.newItems.JobNumber,
        JobName: $scope.newItems.JobName,
        JobDescription: $scope.newItems.JobDescription,
    }
    $http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data).success(function (data, status, headers) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.cancelNewJobModal();
        $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
            $scope.data;
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Why do you need $evalAsync?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do it, I thought I would need to use $apply or $digest but after doing reading it said to us $evalAsync. I did not know what to look for. before I was just using windowreload but I would like something that doesnt reload the entire page

Comment: Wait, I don't see the need of using any digest trigger since the call is  made with $http, the response should be already in sync with the digest cycle. I wonder if the problem is hidden somewhere else.

Comment: Do you mean to set `$scope.data` to something?

Comment: no, i was just plugging stuff in to see what it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, it's not clear what you want to achieve.

I see from your code, that you are posting a job to save it. First, is the server saving correctly, and what is the response (e.g. data in the success handler)? Then, if you have an array of jobs in your scope, you have to push the new item to the array manually.

So to give a hint, here's your code snippet, modified to push the new job to a collection:

```
//Post New Job
$scope.submitJob = function () {

    var data = {
        JobId: $scope.newItems.JobId,
        JobNumber: $scope.newItems.JobNumber,
        JobName: $scope.newItems.JobName,
        JobDescription: $scope.newItems.JobDescription,
    };

    $http.post('/api/apiJob/PostNewJob', data)
        .success(function (data, status, headers) {

            // Clone newItem, newItem is a reference
            var tmpNewItem = angular.copy($scope.newItem);

            // This assumes you have $scope.jobslist as your collection
            // Now we can attach cloned newItem to collection
            $scope.jobslist.push(tmpNewItem)

            // Reset newItem, no need for $apply like this
            angular.copy({}, $scope.newItem);

            $scope.cancelNewJobModal();
        });
};
```

I setup a quick example for pushing the new item (without the $http) here http://jsfiddle.net/yy3mrh34/3/

Also, in your code sample update seems to work, because of the two-way data binding. Angular is changing the values instantly and does not depend on the server to save correctly.